# How to new a string[] ?

Tags: c++

I want to new a `StringArray` as follow:

```
class Test
{
public: 
    QString* str[];
    Test() {
        str = new QString[];
    }
};
```

is there some wrong: about `str = new QString[]` ?

Comment: Chances are that you really want something more like `std::vector<QString>` (or use one of Qt's collections).

Comment: Qt already has `QStringList` as a built-in typedef; I suggest looking into that.

Comment: yeah! i know QStringList, but i just want to the mechanism about c++ how to do that,, In my memory, c++ can't do that, but i forget..i am not sure..Aha..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify a size for the array.

Note that there is special syntax for the `delete` operator when deleting an array as well:

```
QString* strings;
strings = new QString[10];
delete[] strings;
```

If you want a dynamic array, consider using STL vector (`std::vector<QString>` in this case) instead.

Comment: by the way, Can it be initialized like Assignment ， string[] = {"USA", "CHINA"} , ? thanks for your help..

Comment: @Tu_JianWu In C++11 it can be: `QString *arr = new QString[10] {"abc","def"};` Whether you can use that depends on your compiler.

Comment: @ravuya: That actually wouldn't be correct. The `[]` on the declaration would make `strings` a pointer to a pointer. The correct declaration would be `QString* strings;`.

Answer (score 2):

```
QString* str[];
```

Declares a array of the type `QString*`. If you need a single string, what you need is, simply:

```
QString* str;
str = new QString;
```

However, Usually You don't need to do allocate dynamic memory explicitly. `QString` would provide its own memory management.

If you need a collection of strings, You are much better off using an container class like vector.

```
QVector<QString> str;
```

Comment: if i change it to <code>QString* str;</code> , there is a wrong : expected primary-expression before ']' token, what i want is that i hava a point that point to a string list , like "USA", "CHINA", "ENGLAND", then , how can i do ?  thanks for help ...

Answer (score 1):

The size must be specified, or it won't work.

```
str = new QString[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

`QString* str[]` declares an array of `QString` pointers. A pointer is more or less synonymous with an array. If you just want an array of `QString`'s, you should do this:

```
QString* str;
Test() {
    str = new QString[10];
}
```

This will make `str` point to an array of 10 `QStrings`.  The `[]` in your declaration is incorrect unless you would want to make a 2D array. Of course, if you do this, make sure to remember to `delete [] str;` at some point to release your memory.

If the size of your array is known at compile time, you're better off not using any dynamic allocation at all:

```
QString str[10];
Test() { }
```

This code will work the exact same as it does above, but you can avoid dealing with the `new` and `delete`.

Or, as others have suggested, you can just use `std::vector<QString>` and let the STL deal with it.

Comment: thanks for your help..Can it be initialized like Assignment ， string[] = {"USA", "CHINA"} , ?

Comment: @Tu_JianWu: I'm not familiar with Qt, but I don't see why you wouldn't be able to. However, you'd only be able to do it within a function. This: `class Test { QString str[] = {"USA", "CHINA"}; Test() { } };` isn't allowed by the C++ standard unless you're using C++11.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [QStringList](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qstringlist.html)

Comment: oh, no,, i know QStringList, but i just want to know c++ whether can implement it directly  、 thanks for your help..